# Sorting get_post_ancestors array

Tags: sort

I have written this code for my breadcrumbs (i'll give only the part that I have problem with):

```
} elseif (is_page()) {
    if($post->post_parent){
        $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );

        foreach ( $anc as $ancestor ) {
            $output = '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($ancestor).'" title="'.get_the_title($ancestor).'">'.get_the_title($ancestor).'</a></li><li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>';
            echo $output;
        }
```

So for a page I'm getting the array of ancestors and it works fine if I have single ancestor. When I have two of them or more then (by default as the codex states):

`The direct parent is returned as the first value in the array. The highest level ancestor is returned as the last value in the array.`

And that echoes out

`HOME > PARENT 2 > PARENT 1 > PAGE TITLE`

How can I sort the $anc array so I could reverse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Thought I need some special WP func to do it and as it turns out the simple answer is the best.

```
krsort($anc);
```

Comment: or just `array_reverse`

Comment: I reckon `array_reverse` is the correct answer. The keys (which reflect the ID’s) do not *necessarily* reflect the hierarchy. A page can become a parent after its children a created.